# Restrict user to only one custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I am new to wordpress, i create a custom post type called news and i need to restrict access to one user, to only this custom post type.

I am using wordpress 5.3, i do install the advanced custom fields plugin to create this custom page.

Which are my options? to create custom functions inside functions.php or install any plugin to create this custom role with acces only to this custom post type?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use roles to accomplish this. Check this tutorial here: https://3.7designs.co/blog/2014/08/restricting-access-to-custom-post-types-using-roles-in-wordpress/

I would have just put this as a comment but I guess I have to have more reputation on this site.